# Page Builders and WP Multisite

Tags: multisite

I'm fairly conversant in Wordpress—been using it for like 13 years and I've built a small handful of themes/plugins over the years—but I have a client project that's dealing with WP Multisite, with which I don't have a ton of experience.

They have an existing site running an off-the-shelf theme (paid, if that matters). It's also running a smattering of plugins including the WPBakery page builder, which they've used to construct most of the static pages on the site.

They're looking to make this site the "reference" site and make duplicates of it (including customizations), but have a handful of variables that can be modified on individual sites—logos, specifically.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how this would be possible. My understanding is that I can push theme changes to the network sites, but since plugin options and so forth are stored in the database, I may need to make those customizations on each site by hand.

I've done a fair bit of Googling about this, but I'm not finding any definitive answer one way or the other.

So, my question(s):

- Am I able to duplicate customizations (made via plugins, not in theme code) among network sites?
- If so, how?

Please let me know if I can provide more information that'd make answering this easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [THIS](https://www.wpkube.com/manage-multiple-wordpress-sites-one-dashboard/).  You can link all your sites to a main site's dashboard and control a lot of things from one central location.  I used MainWP before and thought it was fairly nice.  I had each site setup with its own WP install using the same custom theme. I created an options page for the theme, using [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), which would control minor changes like the logo and some colors.